# Skype Web SDK Sign in not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, skype, skypedeveloper

I'm using the Skype SDK entry point source from https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn962162(v=office.16).aspx and trying to sign into Skype but I keep hitting an issue with one of the Skype functions. I currently have 2 text fields both, which have its own ID values (#username and #password) and I have 2 buttons (#signin and #signout).

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<SCRIPT type='text/javascript' SRC='https://swx.cdn.skype.com/shared/v/1.1.23.0/SkypeBootstrap.min.js'></SCRIPT>
    <TABLE CLASS='test'>
<TR><TD ALIGN=RIGHT><INPUT TYPE=TEXT class=suptabde NAME="username" ID="username" VALUE="" MAXLENGTH=40 style="width:18em">
<INPUT TYPE=PASSWORD class=testtabde NAME="password" VALUE="" MAXLENGTH=40 style="width:18em">
<BUTTON id='signin' class='testtabde' STYLE='text-align:center' VALUE='  Skype Login  '>Log in</BUTTON><BUTTON id='signout' class='suptabde' STYLE='text-align:center' VALUE='  Skype Login  '>Log out</BUTTON>
</TABLE>
```

I have taken a copy of the js content from the msdn website, which looks like the following,

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';    // create an instance of the Application object;
    // note, that different instances of Application may
    // represent different users
    var Application
    var client;
    Skype.initialize({
        apiKey: 'SWX-BUILD-SDK',
    }, function (api) {
        Application = api.application;
        client = new Application();
    }, function (err) {
        alert('some error occurred: ' + err);
    });
    // whenever state changes, display its value    
    client.signInManager.state.changed(function (state) {
        $('#application_state').text(state);
    });
    // when the user clicks on the "Sign In" button    
    $('#signin').click(function () {
    // start signing in
    client.signInManager.signIn({
        username: $('#username').text(),
        password: $('#password').text()
    }).then(
        //onSuccess callback
        function () {
            // when the sign in operation succeeds display the user name
            alert('Signed in as ' + client.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.displayName());
        }, 
        //onFailure callback
        function (error) {
            // if something goes wrong in either of the steps above,
            // display the error message
            alert(error || 'Cannot sign in');
        });
    });

// when the user clicks on the "Sign Out" button
$('#signout').click(function () {
    // start signing out
    client.signInManager.signOut()
        .then(
            //onSuccess callback
            function () {
                // and report the success
                alert('Signed out');
            }, 
        //onFailure callback
        function (error) {
            // or a failure
            alert(error || 'Cannot sign in');
        });
});
});
```

When loading up my html page the error I get following error,
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signInManager' of undefined". The line it points at with the error is "client.signInManager.state.changed(function (state) {". I can see that 'signInManager' is in the SDK-build.js file, which is picked up by the source correctly from swx.cdn.skype.com/vs/SDK-build.js so I'm not sure how to get around this, has anyone got any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I suppose ur js files are in header ?

Comment: They aren't in the header as such, it appears in the body of the html. We generally have js references in the body, which works fine for other stuff so I don't think having it in the header will make a difference unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Issue seemed to be related to 2 references to the jquery library, one, which was older than the other. Have removed the old reference and the error message has now gone.