# Skype Web API "Get not supported" error on "https://pipe.skype.com/Collector/3.0/"

Tags: javascript, office365, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

When experimenting with the sample code from the Microsoft getting started [pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/gettingstarted), the code from various sources (even from other questions in here) always leads me to the same error:
Some internal Javascript tries to call this [page](https://pipe.skype.com/Collector/3.0/) and then causes the error

> Element not found.

If I call this page manually, it simply says

> HTTP GET not supported

Now later I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201291/skype-for-business-web-sdk-samples-not-working) that somehow seems to be related, as the guy also tries to do this with an Office365 account (same as me), but the current online documentation doesn't really make it clear for me if this is now (June 2016) any different then end of 2015.

BTW, the sample code is exactly like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633279/skype-web-sdk-sign-in-not-working) (The mentioned bug in the question is not related, the code can be stripped down to not use jquery parameters/HTML-ID-lookup).

To make it short: is the sample supposed to work with O365? Why is it acting up so weirdly? Assuming the worst: is there an alternative to achieve connection to Skype for Business inside O365 with a lightweight Javascript or maybe even C# application? Me being sad now :-(.

**UPDATE**:

I found a hint on GitHub public release page that the officially support Office365. See the [samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-samples/tree/master/SkypeWebSDKOnlineSample), they are now split into "on premise" and "online/o365" samples. This doesn't help me, but it makes me hope someone has an idea about my problem :-/.

Comment: You are probably best served taking a look at how to sign-in to the Skype Web SDK via Online at [Developing Web SDK applications for Skype for Business Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/developwebsdkappsforsfbonline) or looking at the [ucwa.skype.code/websdk](https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk) specifically at the Azure AD sample.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sign in to Skype For Business Online using the sample as an [example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-samples/tree/master/SkypeWebSDKOnlineSample).

Regarding your particular error - pipe.skype.com is the telemetry pipeline and this should work without any authentication. Can you share a Fiddler trace of the problem? Also, errors in the telemetry pipeline should not prevent you from signing in. Please share more details so we can take a look.

Comment: I have a question on the samples I linked: are they both using the same basic javascript libraries? After opening the sample you linked (and which I also referenced but did not test yet) it looks much bigger+much more complex than the other CDN based library. Or is the CDN only hiding the details and pulling the same files in the background?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The samples pull down the Skype Web SDK code required to talk to the Skype Server through UCWA.
If you look at https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-samples/blob/master/SkypeWebSDKOnlineSample/UI/index.html you'll see its downloading a boostrapper script that gets things started.
Your application needs to do something similar.
Also, not sure what you mean by 'other CDN based library'. The samples are only a reference on how to interact with the sdk. You don't actually link your application to the samples.

Comment: What I mean is this: my initial linked samples use a single Javascript library to execute the Skype service communication. In the other samples it looks like more libraries are required locally in the project and are included already in the project. But that is a smaller problem to me really. what worries me more is that your linked sample looks like it must be deployed as an Azure service somehow to execute the API calls. Is this the case?

Comment: We probably used jQuery in the samples. But you don't have to do so. The only dependency is the bootstrapper that finds the correct version of the Skype Web SDK and downloads it for you.
Also, regarding your question about Azure deployment - The SDK is client side code. However, to be able to log in to Skype for Business Online you need to authenticate the user trying to log in. This is done through Azure Active Directory auth so you need to create an "application" (not code, just an entry in Azure) that specifies what permissions the user signing in is provided, etc.